# Add dynamic property to existing child properties in javaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I know this sounds simple, but especially in this scenario it is not.
lets say I've an object

```
let garageForm = {}
```

I know If I want to add property I can use the following methods

```
Object.defineProperty(params...)
Obj.property=value
Obj[prop]=value
```

if I add property using the last method it works fine e.g.

```
let key='garage'
let garageDetails = {
    nameEnglish:'Mirqab',
    others:'someProps',
}
garageForm[key]=garageDetails

//outputs of garageForm is as follows
garage: {nameEnglish: "Mirqab", others: "someProps"}
```

Now the real problem for lies here, I want to add the dynamic properties to to `garage` property of my `garageForm` object,
If I use the same method above I don't get my desired results

```
let ownerKeyName = 'garage.owner'
let ownerValue = {name: 'foo',phone: '123'}
garageForm[ownerKeyName] = ownerValue
```

Now if print the value of my `garagForm` object, it shows like this

`{garage: {…}, garage.owner: {…}}`

whereas, I want my results to look like this

`garage: {nameEnglish: "Mirqab", others: "someProps", owner: {…}}`

meaning that I want the newly added property to be the of `garageForm.garage` and not the `garageForm` itself.

how can I achieve my required output
thanks in advance

Comment: There's no built-in functionality for this in JS, you have to either use something like `lodash/set` (https://docs-lodash.com/v4/set/), or implement the same by yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let garageDetails = {
    nameEnglish:'Mirqab',
    others:'someProps',
}
const garageForm = { garage: garageDetails };
garageForm.garage.owner = {name: 'foo',phone: '123'};
```

If you need the dynamic values:

```
let garageDetails = {
    nameEnglish:'Mirqab',
    others:'someProps',
}
const key='garage';
const garageForm = {};
garageForm[key] = garageDetails;

const ownerKey = 'owner';
garageForm[key][ownerKey] = {name: 'foo',phone: '123'};
```